# jquery add months to date using date.js

Tags: jquery, date

I am using date.js and i want to add a certain number of months to a set date

this code here works fine which adds 1 month to today

```
var start_date = $("#start_date").val();

expiry_date = Date.now().addMonths(1);

$("#expiry_date").val(expiry_date.toString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
```

but i want to add 1 month to my `start_date` variable, however when i use

```
expiry_date = start_date.addMonths(1);
```

i get an error telling me that `start_date` is not a valid function

UPDATE:

```
$("#start_date, #payment_period").on('change', function() {
    var start_date = Date.parse($("#start_date").val());
    var period = $("#payment_period").val();

    expiry_date = start_date.addMonths(period);

    $("#expiry_date").val(expiry_date.toString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
});
```

This is the code i am now using, which works fine but if there is a value already in the `#start_date` input when the page loads and one of the inputs has a change it is not showing the correct date.

for example, if the page loads with `12-12-2016` in the `#start_date` input, and i change this to `13-12-2016` with the `period` being `24` the `#expiry_date` input changes to `13-09-2109` where it should be `13-09-2019`

its working fine if i clear the `#start_date` input and enter a new value but its not working for the existing value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var start_date = Date.parse($("#start_date").val());
var period = parseInt($("#payment_period").val());
```

**UPDATE:**

you can trigger `change` event via `.trigger('change')` or calling method `.change()` directly when document is ready.

**For example**:

`$("#start_date, #payment_period").change()`

as `date.js` method `addMonths()` requires a `Number` parameter you should first coerce your period to be a number (via `parseInt()`) and check if it's not a `NaN`

Comment: this works - check my update, i have encountered a further problem

Comment: Code-only answers aren't useful to the community. Please look at [answer]

Comment: should your update help with the problem i am experiencing?

Comment: @charlie yes, it should help